# Filter with map but keep the indice

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I wanna to filter and then map the array of object, but when do this the filter make a new array and give me different indices, is possible to do this using filter or should i use another way.

```
this.props.todos = [
          {
            task:'Daily meet',
            status:'incomplete'
          },
          {
            task:'Play videogame'
            status:'complete'
          }
]

this.props.todos.filter(todos => todos.status === 'complete').map((todos, i) => {

 return (<p>{todos.status} - Everythin Ok</p>)
 //here i got i = 0

}));
this.props.todos.filter(todos => todos.status === 'incomplete').map((todos, i) => {

  return (<p>{todos.status} - You have some task incomplete</p>)
  //and here i got i = 0 too i wanna this to be like the original array
}));
```

Comment: Don't use filter, just `map`. Check the status, and if it's the other one, just return `null` instead of a `<p>`.

Comment: You have two elements in one array and it looks like you want two arrays with one element each. If each new array has only one element, how can it have the same indices? Also, you are not saving the return value from filter. It doesn't filter in place, so at the moment your code doesn't really do anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `map`, no need to filter. You can return either component like this:

```
this.props.todos = [
  {
    task: 'Daily meet',
    status: 'incomplete'
  },
  {
    task: 'Play videogame'
    status: 'complete'
  }
]

this.props.todos.map(todo => {
  if (todo.status === 'complete') {
    return (<p>{todo.status} - Everythin Ok</p>);
  }

  if (todo.status === 'incomplete') {
    return (<p>{todo.status} - You have some task incomplete</p>);
  }

  return null;
})
```